# How do I access member variables of a contract from web3.eth?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js

For example:

```
enum Stages {
    AcceptingBookings,
    StopAcceptingBookings,
    Finished
}

Stages public stage = Stages.AcceptingBookings;
function rand ( uint256 param) atStage(Stages.AcceptingBookings) returns (uint256){}
```

In the above, when the contract is in state 'Stages.AcceptingBookings' only code within that function will run, pretty cool..

I just need to be able to access it via web3.eth though and I cant see clear explanation. If anyone knows please let me know 
I want to check what stage I am at from web3.eth if it is possible.

The above code is from the Solidity docs on State Machine:
https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/common-patterns.html#state-machine

Works great from geth, just trying to work out the syntax for web3.eth

Comment: I see various uses of web.eth and web3.eth, can you please make them all the same thing if that's what you meant?

Comment: please fix the title to more generic, e.g. "How do I access member variables of a contract from web3"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

public members of Solidity contracts have an automatic getter method created, it would look something like this:

```
contractInstance.stage(callback)
```

For general API on contract methods see [See Calling Contract Methods Docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)